# Bot Framework - creating/extending similar bots

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

Is there a way to extend a bot published and create similar one without much changes?

Below is a use case - 
Creating bots for a multi-region site - there is a bot for the US region and for Europe I need to create the similar bot, but with some UI changes and some changes in the user/dialog flow.

I can add conditions in code and separate the logic and have both region pointing to same app. Wanted to know if there is a better way?

Comment: You can take a look at the on-going project in the Microsoft/AI repo for the Virtual Assistant bot (overview): https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/tree/master/docs/virtual-assistant . It's a ROBUST, multi-lingual bot that can handle users from different areas. Link to actual code here: https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/tree/master/solutions/Virtual-Assistant/src/csharp/assistant

Comment: I was mainly looking for a deployment model where the customization done on a bot application can be easily extended or copied when you create similar bots for similar purposes. Currently, I need to publish a new bot and redo all my customization on the new bot.